# Range and kernel of a linear transformation are ALWAYS disjoint

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Is  it true that the Range and kernel of a linear transformation are ALWAYS disjoint. I think they are not but I remember in my notes that the ker L= Im (L') this was under projections. So I am unsure about the answer

Comment: Presumably by "disjoint" you really mean "intersect only at the zero vector".  In either case, counterexamples have been provided in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

No, they can intersect non-trivially.  They can even be identical.  Consider, for example, the linear transformations $T_1,T_2$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $T_1$ is projection onto the $y$ coordinate, and $T_2$ is a clockwise rotation by 90 degrees.  Then the composition $T=T_2\circ T_1$ is a linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose kernel and range are both the $x$-axis.

For a formula, $T$ is the map $(x,y)\mapsto (y,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in order to avoid trivialities we should better talk of linear operators, i.e.  homomorphism maps from a vector space to itself, but even then it is false, as

$$0\in\ker T\cap \text{Im}\,T\;,\;\;T:V\to T\;\;\text{a linear operator}$$

Comment: Oh i get you. Thats very smart. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Old question but posting a more complete answer for future.]

Another counterexample is the matrix [1 -1; 1 -1].
Its range and kernel are both spanned by [1 1]

The correct statement which follows from the [fundamental theorem of linear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_linear_algebra) is that the range of $A$ and kernel of $A^T$ are disjoint 
(a. barring $0$ of course) (b. infact it is orthogonal complement).

Answer (score 0):

In complex vector space, range and kernel of a linear transformation A are identical
if and only if range(A) + range(A*) form the whole space.
Goetz Trenkler, Dortmund, Germany