# Kernel and range

Tags: linear-algebra

Can an element of kernel if a matrix $A$ be in its range?(except the trivial case: $A$ has $0$ in the kernel)

If so, wha condition should we impose on the matrix $A$?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about this for a bit? I'd like to see what you've thought about.

Also note that this is clearly not true always: If $A$ is a matrix for a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, the kernel and range are totally different.

Comment: This question is popular. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551105/range-and-kernel-of-a-linear-transformation-are-always-disjoint

Answer (score 4):

Yes:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ is in the null space and range.

By what condition should we impose on $A$, do you mean what condition can we impose so that $\mathrm{Null} A \cap \mathrm{Im} A = \{0\}$?

Comment: Actually, I once thought this should not happen if a matrix is not injective. But your example disproves my guess.